# How do I select the unformatted text only in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

So if I have a page like this:

```
<p><strong>Description</strong><br>Freehold Terrace House Three Floor 4 Room(s) Garden Out Building Vacant</p>
```

How do I select the texts that is not formatted only?

The following would print "DescriptionFreehold Terrace House Three Floor 4 Room(s) Garden Out Building Vacant":

```
console.log(document.getElementByTagName('p')[0].textContent);
```

See code snippet simulator:

```js
console.log(document.getElementsByTagName('p')[0].textContent );
```

```html
<p><strong>Description</strong><br>Freehold Terrace House Three Floor 4 Room(s) Garden Out Building Vacant</p>
```

But now, how I make it to print only "Freehold Terrace House Three Floor 4 Room(s) Garden Out Building Vacant"

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`wholeText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Text/wholeText) like this:

```js
const p = document.getElementsByTagName('p')[0];
const result = Array.from(p.childNodes).find(x => x.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE).wholeText;

console.log(result);
```

```html
<p><strong>Description</strong><br>Freehold Terrace House Three Floor 4 Room(s) Garden Out Building Vacant</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `innerHTML` could let you manage your string better.

```js
console.log(document.getElementsByTagName('p')[0].innerHTML.split("<br>")[1]);
```

```html
<p><strong>Description</strong><br>Freehold Terrace House Three Floor 4 Room(s) Garden Out Building Vacant</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

@guerric-p's answer is correct and will provide greater flexibility if you're working with other elements that may not follow the same structure. However, if all of your use cased **do** follow the same structure, you can leverage `lastChild` for brevity.

**Note:** I also changed `getElementByTagName` to `querySelector`.

```js
const p = document.querySelector('p');
const result = p.lastChild.wholeText;

console.log(result); // Freehold Terrace House Three Floor 4 Room(s) Garden Out Building Vacant
```

```html
<p><strong>Description</strong><br>Freehold Terrace House Three Floor 4 Room(s) Garden Out Building Vacant</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Other answers rely on tags but if you want only to find strings in a text without any format then You can use string.match() function with Regex to select in a unformatted text for example in your case what after ***Description*** is

```js
var string=document.getElementsByTagName('p')[0].textContent;
console.log(string);
console.log(string.match(/(?<=Description).*/));
```

```html
<p><strong>Description</strong><br>Freehold Terrace House Three Floor 4 Room(s) Garden Out Building Vacant</p>
```

You can learn here [how to use match()](https://javascript.info/regexp-methods) function  and with this link you can learn [RegEX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)

Answer (score 0):

First, let me fix your code:

- The `<br>` tag is not closing correctly. it should be closing by `<br />`.

Second, if I understand correctly, the "unformatted" text is only the text that is not bold.
If so, you can write it in two different tags use the function `getElementByTagName`.

This is the HTML code:

```
<strong>Description</strong>
<br />
<p>Freehold Terrace House Three Floor 4 Room(s) Garden Out Building Vacant</p>
```

```
console.log(document.getElementByTagName("p")[0].innerHTML.split("<br>")[1]);
```

Comment: HTML does not require <br> to be closed, and crawled HTML from webpages are always raw, provided as it. Your solution is not universal enough to work in cases without linebreak in them.